# Set starting point for UsedRange

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a combobox drop down that populates items from a list, with a function to filter to dropdown options by characters type in the combobox gathered by the following code

```
Option Explicit

Private cLstPrior As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChangePrior(ByVal Target As Range)
    cLstPrior = Application.Transpose(Database.Columns("1:1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)) 'set module-level variable
    Tool.priorCmb.List = cLstPrior        'initialize ComboBox to range Col A (UsedRange only)
    Tool.priorCmb.ListIndex = -1     'set ComboBox value to empty
End Sub

Private Sub priorCmb_Change()
   filterComboListPrior Tool.priorCmb, cLstPrior
End Sub

Private Sub priorCmb_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Tool.priorCmb.DropDown
End Sub

Private Sub priorCmb_GotFocus()   'or _MouseDown()
    Tool.priorCmb.DropDown
End Sub

Public Sub filterComboListPrior(ByRef cmbPrior As ComboBox, ByRef dLstPrior As Variant)
    Dim itmPrior As Variant, lstPrior As String, selPrior As String


    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With cmbPrior
        selPrior = .Value
        If IsEmpty(cLstPrior) Then cLstPrior = Worksheets("Database").Columns("1:1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
        For Each itmPrior In cLstPrior
            If Len(itmPrior) > 1 Then If InStr(1, itmPrior, selPrior, 1) Then lstPrior = lstPrior & itmPrior & "||"
        Next
        If Len(lstPrior) > 1 Then .List = Split(Left(lstPrior, Len(lstPrior) - 2), "||") Else .List = dLstPrior
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The data the combobox needs to populate with is all from Column 1 in this case, any cell with characters in it.
The issue is that there are blank cells at A1 and A2, so blank entries populate the combobox dropdown later on. I am trying to force the range to only include cells with values in them, but am getting an application-defined or object-defined error at `If IsEmpty(cLstPrior) Then cLstPrior = Worksheets("Database").Columns("1:1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)`
I can't seem to figure this out. Also, is my `Application.Transpose` behavior correct or not needed?

Comment: Is the listbox configured to display one column or more than one?

Comment: Try `Set rngNewTarget = Intersect(Target,Target.Offset(0,1))`? The idea is to use intersect to remove the left most column.

Comment: @ExcelHero it is one column, that needs to start at A3 and check everything there and after in A. If a value is added in a cell below what was previously the last cell, the item must be in the dropbox just after being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Intersect to exclude columns

```
With Worksheets("Database")
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(.UsedRange.Rows(2), .Cells.Resize(.Columns.Count - 1).Offset(1))
    End With
```

Change the line in question to the newly defined range

```
If IsEmpty(cLst) Then cLst = rng
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
Database.UsedRange.Rows(2)
```

Try:

```
Database.Range(Database.Cells(2,2),Database.Cells(Database.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2))
```

Comment: Hi, what does the Count part do here? When I use this suggestion, the dropdown shows Cell B2 (correct) but then goes all the way down B (B3, B4...B2000). I would like to go from B2, C2.... (last Column with characters)2, which needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

May be best to use specialcells, and loop through the cells that have values.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rRng As Range, c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Database")

    Me.ComboBox1.Clear

    Set rRng = ws.Rows("2:2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    For Each c In rRng.Cells
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem c
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I editing my code on my post to reflect entirely what's going on. I used your new way of expressing the range, but did not change the adding to combobox behavior, which I may need to if the current error can't get ironed out. Using the entire block you helped with would have introduced problems later on in the code, which I have added to the post.